# Monitor bandwidth per directory

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, nginx, bandwidth

I have `uploads` directory and I would like to count the total downloads of files in that directory, in short, is it possible to monitor the consumed bandwidth per directory?

Answer (score 4):

Analyze the web server access logs with tools such as [Webalizer](http://www.webalizer.org/) or [visitors](http://www.hping.org/visitors/). See the number of bytes & files transferred. Done.

Comment: Can I log requests for a certain directory only?

Comment: `grep -i "/your/directory/" /path/to/access/log >/tmp/somedir_access.log` and analyze the `somedir_access.log` with the tool of your choice.